# Calling AnchorPoint method

Tags: objective-c

I found this piece of code that resizes an object's layer to keep the position of an object the same when changing its anchorpoint. I am very sure the code itself works, as many users commented how it works perfectly. But as a newbie, I don't know how to call this method. I want to change a Ball object's anchorpoint to (0.5, 0.5) from (2.0, 0.5).

```
-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view{
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x,
                                   view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x,
                                   view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

    newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
    oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

    CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

    position.x -= oldPoint.x;
    position.x += newPoint.x;

    position.y -= oldPoint.y;
    position.y += newPoint.y;

    view.layer.position = position;
    view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

I've tried many variations of

```
[self setAnchorPoint:{0.5, 0.5}anchorPoint forView:(Ball*)];
```

to no avail

Comment: The code you posted is not C#, it's Objective-C. It's not clear from your question whether you actually want an Objective-C solution or not. Assuming you do, your question is still deficient in that all you've shown is the code that as far as you know works perfectly. You need to provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead. What _specifically_ are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to make the Ball object stay in place when I change its anchorpoint. I know the above code achieves this, but I don't know how to use it. Also, I meant Objective-C.

Comment: This question looks like you have no idea how objective-c works or how to read or use it. I don't think any answer is going to help you here - you need to look at some basic language guides.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
[self setAnchorPoint:{0.5, 0.5}anchorPoint forView:(Ball*)];
```

My Code:
You should use the objective C code, for calling the method.

```
[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.5) forView:Ball];
```

for your reference visit the link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm, 
http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/methods

Comment: OH jesus thank you so much. I seriously tried so many variations, but never thought of putting CGPointMake in front of the anchorpoints. You truly are a life saver.

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 is my answer helpful for you then please give it correct mark or upvote so that it will be helpful for other developer.